# Losing the ability to access the editor after switching themes

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

New installation, even newer user of Silverstripe (V 4.5);
Losing the ability to access the editor with [URL]/admin after switching theme from "SIMPLE" (default) to theme created from scratch after switching in 'theme.yml'. Switching back to 'SIMPLE' brings back the editor.
Did anyone else have this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Add $Form below $Content, the default $Form is the editor login form.
-resolved-

Answer (score 0):

Try running the url [site_url]/dev/build?flush=1

Comment: Thanks Hemant,
I found that suggestion too, didn't work though.
Turned out, I didn't put the $Form variable underneath the $Content. In the "simple" default theme, the variable is not in the page.ss script, so I didn't figure it out for quite a while.
Thanks for the suggestion, though. Closing question.